# Get the data-category by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got buttons with different `data-category` attributes. How can I get the data-category by referring its id?

```
<button id="fru52" data-category="lychee">Fruit</button>
<button id="veg17" data-category="veggie">Veggies</button>
<button id="des29" data-category="apple-pie">Dessert</button>

$('#getdata').on('click', function(){
    //how do I get the data-category of #veg17 ?
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:-

```
$('#getdata').on('click', function(){
//how do I get the data-category of #veg17 ?
 var dataid=$('#veg17').attr('data-category');
//or
  var dataid=$('#veg17').data('category');
});
```

or on click of `#veg17`

```
 $('#veg17 ').on('click', function(){
//how do I get the data-category of #veg17 ?
 var dataid=$(this).attr('data-category');
//or
  var dataid=$(this).data('category');
});
```

Comment: beautiful. what would be the better option `.attr` or `.data` ?

Comment: Thanks indeed, I didn't realize there was that many differences. so basically using `data()` is the best and most common practice, but in some specific cases you might need `attr()`...